# AngularJS, where to add $http.get

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to add my WebApi into AngularJS. My first attempt with the following controller worked:

```
    function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = [];
    $http.get('/api/Auftraege')
    .then(function (result) {

        // Success
        angular.copy(result.data, $scope.data);
    },
    function () {

        // Error
        alert("Error");
    });

}
```

But now I added ng-table, and I tried it with sample code from their page, that has data hardcoded.

**My question is:**

Where do I add in the following code the '$http.get('/api/Auftraege')'? All variations I tried didnt`work so far.

```
    var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
    controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {

    var data = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                                data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

This worked for me:

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams) {

    $http.get('/api/Auftraege')
        .success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.data = data;

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
            sorting: {
                foo: 'asc'     // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                    $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                                    $scope.data;

                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [ajax example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6) they have. The getData function there looks like this:

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
        // ajax request to api
        Api.get(params.url(), function(data) {
            $timeout(function() {
                // update table params
                params.total(data.total);
                // set new data
                $defer.resolve(data.result);
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

You can make your `get` call in that function and call `$defer.resolve` with the data in your `then` function on the api request. So something like:

```
getData: function ($defer, params) {
    $http.get('/api/Auftraege')
    .then(function (result) {

        //do whatever data processing you need to do here

        //update the total items
        params.total = result.data.length
        //resolve the deferred object with your data, so ng-table can update
        $defer.resolve(result.data);
    },
    function () {
        // Error
        alert("Error");
    });

}
```

I would also keep in mind that you probably should have data access abstracted into a service, rather than making http calls in a controller. (Maybe you've done this and this is simplified code).

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is simplified code, I'm starting to get more into AngularJS, and it is only for testing and playing around. I will update my question with something that works for me now atm.